# Seleccionando checkbox y guardado

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Si tengo un checkbox que marca todos los checkbox por default, sin embargo no me marca la de las otras ventanas, es decir, la pestaña 1 están todos seleccionados, pero las demás no lo están.

Al momento de guardar, no me valida los datos que se seleccionaron. Dentro de la función "accion2" se encuentra el código que registra en caso de que sean más de dos checkbox marcados, sin embargo no entra a esa condi[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]ción, se le agrego un mensaje de "ENTRÓ" para saber que ingresa y no lo respeta.

Sin embargo si lo hago manualmente, seleccionando uno por uno, si entra a dicha condición y lo guarda.introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow, **es importante que leas [ask]** se recomienda colocar el código en la pregunta como texto y no como imágenes, te invito a que hagas el [tour] para que entiendas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes tu primer medalla, saludos !

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco eso ocurre porque los datos de las otras páginas se cargan dinámicamente. Para simular bien el funcionamiento puedes intentar que al cargar la nueva página se compruebe si está marcado el checkbox que marca todos los checkbox como seleccionados y marcar los de esa página.

Ponle un id al checkbox, algo como id="marcar_todos"

```
if (document.getElementById("marcar_todos").checked) {
    // Codigo para obtener todos los checkbox de esta pagina y marcarlos
}
```

Para que te guarde todos los resultados de la búsqueda creo que lo mejor es enviar al servidor los parámetros de búsqueda, obtener todos los resultados de nuevo y, si está marcado el checkbox "marcar_todos", guardar todos esos resultados (o realizar las operaciones que necesites)

Comment: Hola Jose, gracias por la respuesta, el detalle es que los checkbox no sé el ID que tiene, ya que se va autoincrementando es decir, tiene valores de 

a1
a2
a3 

etc... son más de 200 datos los que debe de chequear, saludos